# A question on $x \pmod 1 \in \Bbb R^n$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x \pmod 1 \in \Bbb R^n$ be the fractional portion of $x \in \Bbb R^n$.

With $A\in\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ as orthogonal and $S(x)$ as sum of coordinates of $x$, for which $x\in\Bbb R^n$ does $S(Ax \pmod 1) = S(x \pmod 1)$?

Does the linear combination of eigenvectors of $A$ that correspond to $1$ form part of solution?

Are there any other vectors given easily?

Comment: What is "the linear combination of eigenvectors of A that correspond to $1$"? Do you mean eigenvectors with eigenvalue $1$?

Comment: $1=$ all $1$ vector.